# PyQt process output to QTextEdit full of new lines characters

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have this code to read all the output of a process and paste it in a QTextEdit:

```
def updateDebugOutput(self) :

   data = self.m_process.readAllStandardOutput()
   s = bytearray(data).decode()
   self.m_ui.b_renderOutput.insertPlainText(s)
   self.m_ui.b_renderOutput.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)

   data = self.m_process.readAllStandardError()
   s = bytearray(data).decode()
   self.m_ui.b_renderOutput.insertPlainText(s)
   self.m_ui.b_renderOutput.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
```

The problem is that in the output I have a lot of newline characters that doesn't exist in the original output (running it in a standard cmd doesn't produce these characters). I've tried to .strip the text or replace "\n" character but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the output of `print(repr(bytes(data)))`?

Comment: You haven't given details regarding the command in question or OS/platform but... it's also possible the command behaves differently depending on whether or not stdout/stderr are [associated with a tty](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) or not.